# Can I disable Calibre from doing any conversion?

Tags: calibre, conversion, kobo

I’d like to use Calibre purely for librarying and sync, and I don’t want it do do any conversion between different ebook formats. It is possible to turn off autoconversion when syncing ebooks with my reader (Kobo Aura H2O)?

To give a specific example, I’d like [the Kobo edition](https://standardebooks.org/ebooks/fyodor-dostoevsky/crime-and-punishment/constance-garnett/dist/fyodor-dostoevsky_crime-and-punishment.kepub.epub) of [Standardebook’s Crime and Punishment](https://standardebooks.org/ebooks/fyodor-dostoevsky/crime-and-punishment/constance-garnett) to not be converted to a normal EPUB on loading into Calibre, as it loses a chunk of formatting and the cover when synced. Manually sideloading it into my Kobo retains the cover, chapter progression markers etc etc. This is using latest Calibre (3.7).

Comment: I don't know if you can switch it off, but I know that at least the original epub is preserved by calibre, so you could just restore the original EPUB via the edit metadata menu. Or write a program that traverses the library, looks for the `.original_epub` files and renames them back to `.epub` (after deleting the converted version). That should not take more than 10 lines of code.

Answer (score 2):

In Preferences - Adding Books in Adding Actions tab there is a preference `Automatically convert added books to the current format` You need to click that off. The default is off.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that’s off already. Digging a little deeper, dragging the book onto Calibre does the following:
- Copies it into Calibre’s library, removing the `.kepub` from the name
- Creates a cover.jpg
- Creates a metadata.opf
The problem seems to come during the actual sync.

Comment: Looking on the device at the file Calibre copied over it differs in size (at least according to Finder on macOS). With the Lyrical Ballads kepub file linked in my question it’s 872,170 bytes in the Calibre libary, 871,652 bytes on the Kobo…

Comment: @Robin it seems to extract and generate the .opf and cover but the original is in the directory(ie the name without the extension) - to check this rubn ls or dir on the directory (depending on OS). I have convbeert off and non .epubs do have to be manually converted

Comment: OK, maybe I’m approaching this the wrong way. My problem is that loading a Standardebooks kepub ebook onto my Kobo through Calibre breaks the file, but dragging and dropping it into the storage manually works fine. So presumably Calibre’s doing something somewhere…

Comment: clicking it off  is not woking at all